# Ordering and dividing orders of infinity.

Tags: cardinals, infinity

I read there are an infinite number of orders of infinity.

1. Can they all be ordered, or are there different orders we can identify where we do not know which has the greater cardinality?
2. Is the ratio of the items in one order to a those in a lesser order in itself definable or calculable? If so, is the ratio itself infinity? And of what order? Where do they lie in the rankings?
   (I’m guessing if two infinite sets of numbers have a finite ratio of items, they must have the same cardinality.)

Comment: 1. Yes, cardinal numbers are linearly ordered (that is, always comparable). 2. Not in any meaningful sense, I think.